# Azure Data Factory: Reading doubles with a comma as decimal separator instead of a dot

Tags: formatting, azure-data-factory

I'm currently trying to read from a CSV files ( separated with semicolon ';') with decimal numbers formatted with a comma(,) as a decimal separator instead of a dot (.).

i.e: the number 12356.12 is stored as 12356,12.

In the source's projection, what would be the correct format to read the value correctly?

The format should in Java Decimal Format

[image]

Comment: You can manipulate data in a data flow: `toDouble(replace(replace([Principal], '.', ''), ',', '.'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV file's columnDelimiter is a comma (','), your first concern is how to avoid your number data won't be treated as different columns. Since your number data is stored as `12356,12`, so my suggests as below :

1. Change the columnDelimiter as `|` or other special characters.

2.Set escape char. Please see this description:

[image]

In addition, 12356,12 can't be identified as Decimal format in ADF automatically. And no such mechanism o turn `,` into `.`. So I think you need to transfer data as `string` temporary. Then convert it into Decimal in your destination with java code.

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks for the answer. As stated the column delimiter is a semicolon. So ADF doesn't have an option to turn commas into dots. That's a pity, most languages and cloud solutions have that option available. I won't be using data factory then, it's a bit too shallow for my needs.

Comment: Hi, in a copy job, the decimal separator can be automatically identified as comma by setting the "mapping" > "Type conversion settings" > "culture" to "de-de" - Not sure whether this breaks other conversions, but it hepled us at least.

Answer (score 2):

True answer is in the comments: In the copy job the culture can be defined, which influences the decimal separator. Go to "mapping" > "Type conversion settings" > "culture" and chose en-us, de-de or whatever works for you. Be aware that this will also influence other types like dates.