# Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A character to numeric conversion process

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, informix

I have a simple Data Factory in Azure that reads from a CSV file and writes to an Informix table. I have a problem with decimal columns in Informix database. I can save integers but when I try to save numbers with decimals I have this error:

> ERROR [22018] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A character to
> numeric conversion process
> failed,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [22018] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A character to
> numeric conversion process failed,Source=iclit09b.dll,'

The CSV contains the number with this format, example:

```
XX;22.22;xx
```

If I send the file with this format `XX;22,22;xx` Azure gives an error.

I think that the problem is related with the driver because with JDBC I can perform an update with the decimal column.

I have [this configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx3CW.png) in ODBC. The database locale is `es_ES.819`.

Comment: The default decimal point in `es_ES.819` is comma `','` rather than dot `'.'`.  Consequently, the dot in the data is not valid in that locale.   If you use `cd $INFORMIXDIR/gls/lc11/es_es` and then viewed `0333.lc` (`0x0333` hex equals `819` decimal), you'd find `mon_decimal_point "<comma>"`.

Comment: What's less clear is how to work around the problem.  One possibility might beto use `en_US.819` which will use dot instead of comma.  That might have other unintended consequences, though — like reinterpreting dates in the American MDY4 order instead of DMY4 order.  I'm not sure whether the ODBC driver would pay attention to the `DBMONEY` environment variable; that might override other settings.   You might be able to set `LC_MONETARY` to a suitable value (but I'm not sure what that suitable value might be).

Comment: That looks like a clash between Data Factory and the ODBC driver. Data factory may be using the "default" numeric format (`"."` for decimal) but ODBC, with that ES_ES (region_territory locale) uses `"."` as thousand separator and `","` for decimals.
Try changing the cultural settings in the Data Factory copy job as described here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982516/azure-data-factory-reading-doubles-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator-instead-of`

Comment: Thanks jsagrera, I add cuture es_es and now I don't have an error. But in the database is stored without decimals and interpreted the . as thousand separator. If I change and put a , instead of a . I have this error from azure:  [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A character to numeric conversion process failed,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,

Comment: Umm.... A decimal on the database will be stored as a number, without decimal or thousand separator. The value is only formatted with a separator when it is converted to string and for that, the driver uses whatever format it needs based on the "language_territory" part of the CLIENT_LOCALE.
If the app (Data Factory) sends a string decimal in ES_ES ( like 1.000,123) the driver needs to know which format is using (that is why there is a CLIENT_LOCALE). The application (Data Factory) and the driver (Informix ODBC) need to use the same format to avoid conversion errors.